# XML Schema - can I use unique with enumeration for validation?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I looked into a lot of topics and I still needing some help.

I need to validate a XML that must have 5 elements, each one with an specific value. They can't repeat.

**xml snippet:**
   ...

```
<logger name="br.com.xxxx" additivity="false">
        <level value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-rolling"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="br.com.web.aq" additivity="false">
        <level value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-rolling"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="br.com.data.connector" additivity="false">
        <level value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-rolling"/>
    </logger>

    <!--FACES LOGGER-->
    <logger name="javax.faces" additivity="false">
        <level value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-rolling"/>
    </logger>

    <!--MYFACES LOGGER-->
    <logger name="org.apache.myfaces" additivity="false">
        <level value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-rolling"/>
    </logger>
```

So far my xsd just validate the values list, like this:

---

```
<xsd:element name="configuration">

<xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="3" ref="property"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="appender"/>
    <xsd:element minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="5" name="logger">

    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="level"/>
        <xsd:element ref="appender-ref"/>
    </xsd:sequence>

    <xsd:attribute name="additivity" type="xsd:string" use="required" fixed="false"/>      

    <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required">  

        <xsd:simpleType>            
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
            <xsd:enumeration value="br.com.xxxx"/>  
            <xsd:enumeration value="br.com.web.aq"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="br.com.connector"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="javax.faces"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="org.apache.myfaces"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
 </xsd:attribute>

</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:unique name="uniquity">
      <xsd:selector xpath="logger"/>
      <xsd:field xpath="@name"/>
</xsd:unique>

</xsd:element>
```

But the way it is, the XML can have 2 'loggers' with the same name.

*Updated the xsd with the unique constraint. Missing something to put this validation working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use xs:unique and xs:enumeration in conjunction. Just add an xs:unique constraint to the element declaration for the parent of the logger elements:

```
<xs:unique name="uniquity">
  <xs:selection xpath="logger"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
</xs:unique>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what part of "add it to the element declaration for the parent of the logger elements" isn't clear.

Comment: Just updated the xsd snippet. appreciate all the help.